# Синонимизировать метки [viewpager] и [android-viewpager]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Все вопросы по [viewpager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewpager) касаются Android. Предлагаю синонимизировать с [android-viewpager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-viewpager).

Comment: [Не совсем все](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewpager+-android)

Comment: Интересно. На SO это синонимы. Хм.

Comment: По ссылке @alexolut всего 1 вопрос, касающийся iOS. И, на сколько я знаю, под ios нету компонента `ViewPager` в принципе. Может, всё же, стоит синонимизировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пора апнуть тему. На en SO это синонимы. У нас, если посмотреть [ссылку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewpager+-android) от alexolut, всего [один вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688227/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-ios-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-viewpager-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) с этой меткой, который не касается Android. Да и то это не название компонента системы, а просто заголовок вопроса о компоненте со схожим функционалом.

Давайте уже синонимизируем [viewpager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewpager) к [android-viewpager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-viewpager).

Comment: А какую метку основной сделать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб на en SO основная - android-viewpager. Думаю, нам так же надо.

Comment: Что-то мне в модераторском интерфейсе меток не разобраться) Можете предложить синоним чтобы я его запрувил?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб у меня рейтинга не хватает по метке, чтобы синоним предложить.

Comment: О, я понял как! Готово)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб благодарю (: