# Поправить синонимизированные метки, которые не были объединены

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Небольшое разъяснение по поводу синонимизации: [Синонимизировать метки или объединять? Объединять и синонимизировать! Но это не точно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7306/15479).

**TL;DR: синонимизация != объединение**

В свете последних синонимизаций меток (да и некоторых прошлых), обнаружилось, что модераторы часто именно синонимизируют метки, хотя вместе с этим ещё нужно их объединять.

Хочу в этом треде собрать список таких меток, чтобы модератором было проще завершить процесс синонимизации.

## Как понять, объединены ли метки?

При создании вопроса попробуйте указать метку-синоним. Если при этом вам будет выдавать основная метка, то метки объединены и всё хорошо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же метки были синонимизированы без объединения, то у вас будет возможность указать и неосновную метку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Что требуется от обычных пользователей?

Добавлять в этот вопрос метки синоним + основная с ссылкой на решение о том, какую метку решили делать основной.

## Что требуется от модераторов?

После объединения меток, зачёркивайте метку и переносим в нижний список.

## Будьте внимательны

Перед объединением меток убедитесь в правильности решения, т.к. откатиться в случае ошибки будет весьма проблематично.

---

## Список меток, которые надо объединить

- [jabber](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jabber) и [xmpp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmpp). Основная [xmpp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmpp). Обсуждение: [Синонимизировать [xmpp] и [jabber]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6204/15479)
- [ef-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ef-core), [entity-framework-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core). Основная [entity-framework-core](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/entity-framework-core). Обсуждение: [Синонимизировать [ef-core] с [entity-framework-core]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7268/15479)
- [annotations](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/annotations) и [аннотации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8). Основная [аннотации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8). Обсуждение: [Синонимизировать [аннотации] и [annotations]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6392/15479)
- [reflection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reflection) и [рефлексия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f). Основная [рефлексия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f). Обсуждение: [Метки [reflection] или [рефлексия]?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6380/15479)
- [sqlitedatabase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlitedatabase) и [sqlite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite). Основная [sqlite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite). Обсуждение: [Синонимизировать [sqlitedatabase] и [sqlite]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6203/15479)
- [objects](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objects) и [объекты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b). Основная [объекты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b).
- [ecmascript-6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) и [ecmascript-2015](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-2015). Основная [ecmascript-6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6). Обсуждение: [ES6 & Ecmascript 2015](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1901/15479)

## Список меток, по которым завершили объединение

- [android-intent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent) и [intent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intent). Основная [android-intent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-intent). 
  Обсуждение:  [Синонимизировать [android-intent] и [intent]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7302/15479)
- [viewpager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viewpager) и [android-viewpager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-viewpager). Основная [android-viewpager](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-viewpager). Обсуждение: [Синонимизировать метки [viewpager] и [android-viewpager]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6180/15479)
- [android-asynctask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-asynctask) и [asynctask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asynctask). Основная [android-asynctask](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-asynctask). Обсуждение: [Синонимизировать [asynctask] и [android-asynctask]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6452/15479)